# Need help deleting multiple items from desktop

Tags: desktop

I just accidentally copied nearly 500 pics and videos to my desktop.  Is there a way to delete all items by date from the desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Open the `Desktop` in `Finder`, sort by `Date Modified` or `Date Added`, select desired files and delete.